# How to redirect a path to subdomain using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm new to htaccess, need help regarding redirection a path to subdomain path.

My subdomain is

```
Subdomain :  https://abc.example.com/
```

which is pointing to path

```
Path :  https://example.com/folder1/abc
```

Now I want if someone is accessing directory using path it should redirect to the subdomain

```
Request :  https://example.com/folder1/abc/folder2/file
Redirect : https://abc.example.com/folder2/file
```

I searched a lot but not able to proceed. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Complete my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^api\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://api.example.com/$0 [L,NE,R=301]

ErrorDocument 403     /error-pages/403.php
ErrorDocument 404     /error-pages/404.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `folder1/abc/.htaccess` keep this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abc\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://abc.example.com/$0 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try

Comment: It is redirecting only if I'm accessing https://example.com/folder1/abc/ but if I'm accessing https://example.com/folder1/abc/folder2/file its not working

Comment: Accessing file returning me the result instead first redirect to the subdomain. and yes its my very first rule.

Comment: I did the correction, still its returning me the result. Redirection not working. For your more info. Its my api services url written in basic php, returning me json data. So, I'm receiving the data but redirection not working

Comment: yes, i tried new browser. I think it is not working for pages returning json data. For few its working. weird

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: Hey, now its working, I was having one more htaccess in sub folder with ErrorDocument only. I've removed those and it worked.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to handle error inside the sub folder? Its important

Comment: thanks, I just removed 'RewriteEngine On' in sub folder htaccess and both are working now. Thanks

Comment: Last question, can you suggest some good and easy blog to learn htaccess handle.

Comment: If I'm using my old url to request data I'm getting 301 error, any suggestion for that, it should return the data. :( Do I need to remove R=301?

Comment: Agree its not an error, but in response I'm getting 301 Moved Permanently, and not getting the json data. :( On browser I'm getting the data correctly. but in the request through android app, 301

Comment: See I cannot comment endlessly. SO admins don't like too many comments on any post. You will be better off asking a new question and providing more details on what URL you want to skip from redirection.